# Please explain this awk script

Tags: awk

```
echo "45" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=$i}END{print x}'
```

I want to know how this works,what specifically does awk Fs,NF do here?

Comment: Did you try reading the `awk` manual? It explains very clearly what those two variables are for.

Comment: 1. This isn't a bash script. Written this way it'd work in more-or-less any shell.
2. It isn't specific to Linux at all. It'd certainly work on most any POSIX system. It might even work on Windows if you had `awk` installed.

Comment: @kojiro: I don't believe it would work in the regular Windows shells, due to the use of single-quotes for argument-quoting. You'd have to run it in Bash (or another of your "more-or-less any shell" shells).

Comment: it works i understand what it does but i needed a full explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FS` is the field separator. Setting it to `""` (the empty string) means that every single character will be a separate field. So in your case you've got two fields: `4`, and `5`.

`NF` is the number of fields in a given record. In your case, that's `2`. So `i` ranges from `1` to `2`, which means that `$i` takes the values `4` and `5`.

So this AWK script iterates over the characters and prints their sum — in this case `9`.

Answer (score 1):

These are built-in variables, FS being Field Separator - blank meaning split each character out. NF being Num Fields split by FS... so in this case num of chars, 2.  So split the input by each character ("4", "5"), iterate each char (2) while adding their values up, print the result.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Answer (score 1):

`FS` is the field separator. Normally fields are separated by whitespace, but when you set `FS` to the null string, each character of the input line is a separate field.

`NF` is the number of fields in the current input line. Since each character is a field, in this case it's the number of characters.

The `for` loop then iterates over each character on the line, adding it to `x`. So this is adding the value of each digit in input; for `45` it adds `4+5` and prints `9`.